# Apache Knox for SAML2 authentication keeps using NameIDFormat entity instead of what is configured

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, knox-gateway, apache-knox

I am trying to enable SSO capabilities for Apache Zeppelin, using Apache Knox, which is configured to redirect auth requests to a Siteminder IdP.

The issue I am having is related to the NameID format configuration, and the signing configuration.

No matter what I configure in the sp/idp metadata, the NameID format used is

urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity

And the requests are always being sent with Signed requests set to true.

My SP configuration is as follows:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client">
<SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/07/secext">
<NameIDFormat>
  urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
</NameIDFormat>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client"/>
   <AssertionConsumerService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" index="1" isDefault="true"  Location="https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client"/>
</SPSSODescriptor>
```

I activated a SAML tracer and attempted the logon user journey. The AuthNRequest being sent to the Siteminder IdP based on this configuration looks like this:

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client"
                 Destination="https://test-siteminder.com/test/saml2sso"
                 ForceAuthn="false"
                 ID="_yp52mio0oj4ho2niijmnnaikgbkid9tnc5h5ear"
                 IsPassive="false"
                 IssueInstant="2020-02-17T10:19:24.279Z"
                 ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                 ProviderName="pac4j-saml"
                 Version="2.0"
                 >
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
              Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
              NameQualifier="https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client"
              >https://knox.test.com/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true%26client_name=SAML2Client</saml2:Issuer>
```

I can see a signature value in the Parameters section of the request, which is why I'm assuming that the AuthNRequest is signed (though my understanding of this is minimal, so that could be a wrong assumption!).

Can anyone help explain why the NameIDFormat is coming through as entity, as opposed to unspecified?
Does Apache knox support SAML1 protocols?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned NameID format to be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity` in your post but in the code you pasted it is `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified`, just a copy paste error ? Looks like protocolSupportEnumeration is also referencing SAML 1 protocol. Knox uses [Pac4J](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html) under the hood which does not support SAML 1, this might be the reason.